# How to specify output table name in GeoPackage when using ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr, geopackage

I want to convert a GeoJSON file to a Layer within a GeoPackage.

For this, I'm trying to use the following command:

`ogr2ogr dist.gpkg mah.geojson -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI`

This sucessfully creates a new GeoPackage, with a layer whose name is `mah`.

I want to have control over the name of the output layer.

I have also tried adding a `-lco IDENTIFIER=dist_2019` parameter, but this does set the name to what I want.

What is the correct way to specify the name of the output Table/Layer in the GeoPackage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by using the `-nln` parameter.

The following command should work:

`ogr2ogr dist.gpkg mah.geojson -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -nln dist_2019`

Comment: Ogr2ogr has many options but they are all documented in https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html. In this case `-nln <name>
Assign an alternate name to the new layer`

Comment: Thank you past me!